# quickSearch jQuery plug-in - Handling Live Content?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, quick-search

I'm using the quickSearch jQuery plug-in: 
http://lomalogue.com/jquery/quicksearch/

The reason it's not working currently in my app, is that while my search box remains constant, the table does not...

It's a web app, and the table changes. Problem is the QuickSearch plugin will only search with the first table, if I AJAX in new table contents QuickSearch doesnt work, though if I switch back to that first table it works.

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling it again after the table loads?

```
$('input#id_search').quicksearch('table#table_example tbody tr');
```

Comment: I did but that had no effect. Strange right? I'm using it inside a jQuery UI Tabs model, so every tab click loads new contents. Not sure if that could be a problem?

Comment: I was using tabsselect, as the bind... I think maybe it's bec that happens before the content is loaded. I need something that happens AFTER